# Best way to do a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am using:

```
$query = SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='column';
$mydata = mysql_query($query);
$element = mysql_result($mydata, 0, "Element");
```

Is there a faster and a better way to do the same?

Comment: use `prepared query`

Comment: i am sorry i am new to php and mysql. can you please tell me what is a prepared query?

Comment: read tutorial for it. `http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp` & `http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php` from here.

Comment: Use [PDO](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/09/introduction-to-pdo.html) instead of mysql_* functions because these are deprecated and will be removed in future.

Answer (score 7):

You can use mysql, mysqli or PDO. It depends on your requirement and you have to consider few aspects when you are choosing one.

If you are only considering performance, mysql is the fastest one. Though mysql_* functions deprecated after 5.5.x and will not exist in PHP7.

But if you are considering Database support, API, Named parameters, Object mapping, Prepared statements, Stored procedures, etc, you can choose one between mysqli or PDO. mysqli only support mysql database while PDO support 12 databases.

```
    +--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
    |                    | PDO                  | MySQLi           |
    +--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
    | Database support   | 12 different drivers | MySQL only       |
    | API                | OOP                  | OOP + procedural |
    | Connection         | Easy                 | Easy             |
    | Named parameters   | Yes                  | No               |
    | Object mapping     | Yes                  | Yes              |
    | Prepared statements| Yes                  | Yes              |
    | (client side)                                                |
    | Performance        | Fast                 | Fast             |
    | Stored procedures  | Yes                  | Yes              |
    +--------------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

This [blog](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) has a good comparison between mysqli and PDO

My recommendation is using PDO.

***mysql***

```
$c = mysql_connect("example.com", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM users");
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
var_dump($rows);
```

***mysqli***

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM users");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
var_dump($rows);
```

**PDO**

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM users");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($rows);
```

Comment: If mysql_ is faster, that tiny performance gain would be vastly outweighed by the security/data integrity methods of the modern APIs. MyISAM vs InnoDB would have more impact on performance than mysql_ vs mysqli_

Comment: Please don't advocate the long deprecated `mysql_*` functions that don't even exist anymore in PHP7.

Comment: Also, this blog (and your table) is not totally correct, [mysqli does support prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thanks @Gerald Schneider, I updated table and mentioned mysql_* functions are deprecated.